# How to differentiate between local variable and field name?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, declare

I have a stored procedure in MySQL (actually MariaDB 10.3), and I have a variable declared, let's call it `name`.

Later in my procedure, I want to use my `name` variable to filter a table.  This table has a field *also* called `name`.

How can I use my `name` variable to filter my table on the `name` field?

Here is an example:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE doSomething()
BEGIN
    -- Declare a variable and load a value into it
    DECLARE name CHAR(6) DEFAULT NULL;
    SELECT value FROM tableA WHERE id = 6 INTO name;

    -- Use the variable in a query
    SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE name = name;
END; //

DELIMITER ;

CALL doSomething();
```

As you can see, I load the `name` variable with a value from `tableA`.  Then I want to filter `tableB` using this `name` variable.  Obviously, `WHERE name = name` doesn't work.

How do I refer to my variable alongside the field name?  Something like:

```
WHERE name = _variables_.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are clear that [locally declared variables take scope precedence over column names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/local-variable-scope.html).  So, with respect, your SP suffers from ambiguity. It's confusing and wrong.

But if you qualify your column name with a table name in your SELECT, it works. Like so.

```
SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE tableB.name = name;
```

Comment: Thanks for that link!  I was trying to search for the answer for this, but I was using the wrong keywords.  I suppose that naming a variable the same as a field/column is not a good idea... this code is from a longer procedure and I only _now_ noticed that I made this mistake.  I'll probably go back and change the variable name, but thanks for the help! :-)

Answer (score 2):

**never** use variables that are the same as column names mysql gets confused

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE doSomething()
BEGIN
    -- Declare a variable and load a value into it
    DECLARE _name CHAR(6) DEFAULT NULL;
    SELECT value FROM tableA WHERE id = 6 INTO _name;

    -- Use the variable in a query
    SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE name = _name;
END; //

DELIMITER ;

CALL doSomething();
```